# Function annihilated by ideal in universal envelope

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, differential-operators

Let $G$ be a Lie group, $U(G)$ its universal enveloping algebra over $\mathbb C$ and let $J\ne U(G)$ be a left ideal. We consider $U(G)$ as the algebra of left-invariant differential operators on $G$.
Suppose that $J\ne U(G)$.
Does there exist a non-zero function $f\in C^\infty(G)$, which is annihilated by $J$, i.e., satisfies $Df=0$ for every $D\in J$?